# posterior predictive p-values understating

Tags: predictive-models, p-value, posterior

I seem to misunderstand the calculation process of posterior predictive p-values.

Let's say I have dataset of concentration of 400 different proteins measured in 9 rats. So: $x_{pr}$ for $r=1...9, p=1...400$

The way that I understand posterior predictive p-values should be calculated is:

1) you run your MCMC chain

for each sample $'i'$ in your chain (and each protein $'p'$):

2) you calculate the variance of your actual data $s^{2 (true)}_{p}$

3) you calculate the variance of your simulated data $s^{2 (pred)}_{p}$

4) you calculate $M_{ip} = I(s^{2 (pred)}_{p} > s^{2 (true)}_{p}) \in \{0,1\}$

You use your $M_{ip}$ values to calculate $P(s^{2 (pred)}_{p} > s^{2 (true)}_{p}) \approx \frac{\sum_{i}M_{ip}}{N}$ ($N$ being the total number of samples)

Do I understand this correctly? So overall we have 400 different p-values  ranged between 0 and 1? Also, how should it look like if my model is supposedly good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example seems to be correct. For each protein, you get an estimate $p$ of how probable it is (given the model and priors in question) to obtain a statistic at least as extreme as the one you actually obtained. Very low $p$-values are evidence that your model or priors don't accurately describe the data-generating process, according to the statistic of interest. The higher the $p$-value, the less this is a concern, although it isn't fair to expect a good model and prior to have particularly high $p$-values; it's only fair to expect that they *won't* be extremely low.

One could, in theory, make this procedure more like classical null-hypothesis significance testing by making some sort of decision based on a threshold applied to $p$, but the guy best known for popularizing this approach, Andrew Gelman, doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you. There is something I'm confused about. Don't we want the variance of the predictions and the actual data to be the same? Surely it make sense that the simulated data and the observed data have the same variance, no? In that case, don't we want the p-value to be close to 0.5 (right in the middle) rather than high p-values?

Comment: @Babak Come to think of it, in your example, yes, because you didn't code $p$ in such a way that higher $p$-values always mean less extreme deviations between the model and the data.